# Question about completely antisymmetric unit pseudotensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, notation

In a book, it says for transforming a completely antisymmetric unit pseudotensor from non-curvilinear system $x'$ to  curvilinear system $x$, one can use

$$E^{iklm}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{'p}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{'r}}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial x^{'s}}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial x^{'t}}e^{prst}$$

I understand this part.

1. But then it says it is also:
   $$E^{iklm}=Je^{iklm}$$

Why is that?

2. In the above formula $J$ is defined as
   $$J=\frac{\partial (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)}{\partial (x^{'0},x^{'1},x^{'2},x^{'3})}$$

What is the meaning of $J$ in this definition? Is it a 4x4 matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Concerning subquestion 2: $$J~=~\det J^{i}{}_{j}$$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix with entries $$J^{i}{}_{j}~=~\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime j}}.$$ ($J$ is also known as the [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), cf. deleted answer by Michael Seifert.) So a better notation for OP's last formula would be

$$J~=~\det\frac{\partial (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)}{\partial (x^{'0},x^{'1},x^{'2},x^{'3})}.$$

Subquestion 1 follows from properties of the [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) and the chain rule.

Comment: Probably here the matrix would be $J^{ij}$ ?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to distinguish between a matrix and its (matrix) entries.

Comment: Can you give me more hints to prove 1? I tried 2D case, and finally I need to prove e.g.

$$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{'1}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{'0}}e^{01}=\frac{\partial x^0}{\partial x^{'0}}\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^{'1}}e^{ik}$$

how is $e^{ik}$ related to $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{'k}}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
E^{iklm}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{'p}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{'r}}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial x^{'s}}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial x^{'t}}e^{prst}\;, \\
=\delta_{[a}^i \delta_b^k \delta_c^l \delta_{d]}^m \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{'p}}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^{'r}}\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x^{'s}}\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x^{'t}}e^{prst} \;,\\
=\frac 1 {4!} e^{iklm} e_{abcd}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{'p}}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^{'r}}\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x^{'s}}\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x^{'t}}e^{prst} \;,\\
=\Big(\frac 1 {4!}e_{abcd}e^{prst}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{'p}}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^{'r}}\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x^{'s}}\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x^{'t}}\Big)e^{iklm}\;,\\
=J\;e^{iklm}
$$